# dual cam for stereo

Tags: camera

I am looking to test some applications that need stereo inputs. Similiar to this dual camera.

[https://www.amazon.com/ELP-Megapixel-Camera-Module-Biometric/dp/B00VG32EC2//ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&linkCode=ll1&tag=albertarmeabl-20&linkId=bc5b4947de2850d5a0cec76d2c6a9760](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VG32EC2)

Can anyone please recommend a hardware?

The images should be synced and if possible should be able to send 30 fps ( for 2 cameras 60 fps ). It should have a USB 3.0 connection for fast data transfer.

Comment: What for? It's unusual to need two stereo cameras excluding depth perception, and most solutions tend to use some other sensors as well (see: RealSense, Kinect.) Also, is there anything problematic with just using two separate USB cameras?

Comment: @JMY1000 whats "two stereo cameras" ? stereo is implicitly dual channel. And my application is depth perception. There are tons of problems in using two separate usb cameras for depth perception. where should i start?

Comment: Sorry, should've just been "two cameras in stereo." I'm not familiar with the problems with using two separate cameras. If your application is depth perception, why not use something off the shelf like RealSense?